# Pandoc: Convert tex to word document with in-document bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing, pandoc

In a tex document I used bibliography as follows in the end of document. Now, when I convert the `tex` to `docx` using Pandoc, the output file doesn't contain the citations (However it lists the references).

I know I could use `--bibliography=x.bib` option if I had used a separated file for my bibliographies.

How can I have the citations in this situation?

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{becker} Tilman Becker, HyTag: A new type of TAGs for hybrid syntactic representation of free word order languages. Phd thesis, University of Saarlandes. 1994.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: `pandoc` doesn't really support all LaTeX constructs, in fact it supports only really basic subset. for this task you should use converter with full LaTeX support, like `tex4ht` (it can convert files to `ODT` format, which can be converted to `docx` using LibreOffice). BTW, we need a full example, including the preamble.

Comment: You could use another tool, but if you know Lua you could also write your own Pandoc reader and maybe also modify default ODT/DOCX writer. If you need to convert ODT to DOCX, you can use ``unoconv`` utility from command line, which uses LibreOffice for conversion, but without need for using GUI.

Comment: @Ahmad `Pandoc` is more than suitable for converting `.tex` files with citations into `.docx`, but the prerequisite is that the bibliography is stored in an external file.
You can also use inline references, but they need to be in a `YAML` reference block style, but it makes the `.tex` file unuseable. See the [documentation](http://pandoc.org/README.html#citations) for details. If you have multiple references, you are better off to manage them in a separate file.